# Add numerical order to matching occurrences

Tags: regex, linux, vim, sed

i have some problems.
I have one big file that provide one error with text "it's an error".
In source code I have a lot of lines with same text.
How I can change all this line to counted lines.
 I mean that i want to change it like this:

```
some_function ()
 {
 provide  "it's an error"
  } 
 another_function ()
 provide  "it's an error"
 provide  "it's an error"
```

And now i want to get next:

```
some_function ()
 {
 provide  "1 it's an error"
  } 
 another_function ()
 provide  "2 it's an error"
 provide  "3 it's an error"
```

Or the same but with line numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With line numbers:

```
awk '{gsub(/it.s an error/, NR" &"); print }' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using Vim (as you tagged the post):

```
:let i=1 | g/\zeit's an error/s//\=i." "/g | let i=i+1
```

Or using this other way to enumerate errors with the error line:

```
:%s/\zeit's an error/\=line('.')." "/g
```